# Jest not finding typescript tests

Tags: typescript, jestjs, serverless-framework

I'm trying to write a jest test but it's giving me an odd error.

```
TypeError: jest_1.it is not a function

   9 |
  10 | describe('Health check', () => {
> 11 |     it('GET works', async () => {
```

I'm not sure if posting all the various config files would help so maybe I'll just point out the pieces I'm using: serverless framework with serverless-plugin-typescript plugin, typescript, jest, ts-jest.

My understanding is that ts-jest should be compiling the TS for me and then handing it over to Jest. One thing is I know serverless is opinionated about it's TS configuration so maybe that's causing an issue with ts-jest.

Any ideas about what I should be looking at?

Edit: formatting on code block

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had imported `it` at the top of my test file like so:

`import {it} from 'jest'`

Removing it fixed it. Time to go read about modules.